# Fade out image is showing up in screen when slideshow occurs

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am trying to achieve a slideshow, but during fadeout, image and text are displayed in the bottom for milliseconds before it completely moving away.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first').fadeOut(1000)
    `enter code here`
    .next().fadeIn(1000)
      .end().appendTo('#slideshow');
  }, 9000);
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 403px;
  padding-left: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow > div {
  /*align-items:flex-start;*/
  overflow: visible;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div style="display:inline" align: "left !important" padding-left: "40em;">
    <p style="padding-left:0em;width:200px;height: 0px;text-align: start;"><strong class="b1">our aim is</strong>  <strong class="b2">Dedicated</strong>  <strong class="b3">To conducting business affairs using<br />
    the highest standards</strong>
    </p>
    <img src="images/slider-img1 - Copy.jpg" alt="" style="padding-left:45em;" />
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline" align: "left !important" padding-left: "40em;">
    <p style="padding-left:0em; width:200px;height: 0px;text-align: start;"><strong class="b1">our solidity is</strong>  <strong class="b2">equity</strong>  <strong class="b3">Innovation, flexibility, quick and<br />
    high results - oriented work</strong>
    </p>
    <img src="images/slider-img2 - Copy.jpg" alt="" style="padding-left:30em;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screen-shot of slider]

Comment: I am not able to add screenshot because of less points... Hope my question is clear

Comment: Your posted code looks malformed; the CSS is included in the jQuery block. You've also got some stray *enter code here* comments. Please update.

Comment: Use http://postimage.org/ on the interim. It's a free image hosting service.

Comment: @benjarwar I've reformatted his code as a snippet.

Comment: [link]http://s5.postimg.org/yenb2otrb/slideshow_img.png  I have uploaded image for your reference in postimage.org... Please have a look into it... @benjarwar

Comment: @ClarusDignus Thank you... I am going to implement and let you know

Comment: @HariMohan Not sure if your last comment is for me or EliJah. Please note the answer that's been provided to your question (by EliJah). To respond to it, click the "add a comment" link beneath the answer (rather than adding a comment to your own question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several issues. I started trying to understand your code, but then I realize that making a better example would be faster.

I created this plunk http://embed.plnkr.co/hiD1eNp1LpVaUHv6Tioh/preview that hopefully helps you accomplish what you need.

Take note that inline styles only add complexity to your code and makes it harder to debug and maintain.

If it helps, feel free to accommodate the code to your needs, the delay and speed of transition and intervals, for example.

Let me know if you need help understanding my code.

Comment: +1 for a complete answer with a fully functional demonstration. It would be better practice to use StackOverflow's inbuilt code snippet tool (found in the text editor) to embed the code into your post rather than using external solutions like Plnkr or JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks @Elijah for your code... Not sure what am missing.. For me text and images are displaying one by one ( image at top and text at bottom and followed by another image and so on...) while using code.. could you help me on this.

Comment: @HariMohan Considering the code works perfectly in Plnkr, it's likely that your own code is conflicting with EliJah's code or something has gotten lost in translation. Create a separate folder in your local host directory. Add the pages and code from the Plnkr example as is. Confirm that it works as expected. Then, begin adding your own additional code for the other elements on your page. Test the slider with each addition of code. When the slider breaks, post back the code that caused it to break. Yes, this is tedious but this is nature of debugging and it guarantees a solution.